# Redis on remote server

Tags: redis

Would it make sense to have Redis in a remote, different from the Magento store, server? I am mainly thinking that the communication (overhead) time might be equal (or more?) to Magento without Redis and so defeating the purpose of having it at all.

Answer (score 0):

you only need one separate instance with redis if you have memory limits, or for example you can take admin server down for maintenance, while your frontend servers continue to work.